# SendKey Enter into Browser Control WinForm .Net

Tags: javascript, .net, browser, sendkeys, geckofx

i need to send the Enter key press Event in a Web Page using GeckoFX Web Control.

I can't use SendKeys.Send({ENTER})

Is there a way to send enter via Javascript in a WebPage?

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using geckofx you can use the nsIDOMWindowUtils interface to send the keypress.

```
    var GeckoWebBrowser browser = ...;
    nsIDOMWindowUtils utils = Xpcom.QueryInterface<nsIDOMWindowUtils>(browser.Window.DomWindow);
    using (nsAString type = new nsAString("keypress"))
    {
      utils.SendKeyEvent(type, 0, 13, 0, false);
    }
```

Note one normally can't use the nsIDOMWindowUtils interface from normal javascript, as it requires the UniversalXPConnect privileged.

Answer (score 1):

here is the voodoo magic:

C# COM version, dispatches ENTER keypress to GeckoNode in GeckoWebBrowser.
Unfortunately i havent found suitable wrapper in the GeckoFX 18, so all work is done via xpcom.

13 is the code for enter, if you need to send characters, set it to 0 and use the charcode as the last parameter to InitKeyEvent

Here e is the object youre dispatching key press to.

```
 nsIDOMKeyEvent Event = Xpcom.QueryInterface<nsIDOMKeyEvent>(Browser.Window.DomWindow.GetDocumentAttribute().CreateEvent(new nsAString("KeyEvents")));
 Event.InitKeyEvent(new nsAString("keypress"), true, true, Browser.Window.DomWindow, false, false, false, false, (uint)13, (uint)0);
 Xpcom.QueryInterface<nsIDOMEventTarget>(e.DomObject).DispatchEvent(Event);
```

JavaScript version, if you can inject javascript this will do the same from within javascript environment

```
 var Event = document.createEvent("KeyEvents");
 Event.initKeyEvent('keypress', true, true, window, false, false, false, false, 13, 0);
 e.dispatchEvent(Event);
```